# Fading image in Libre Office

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, transparency

I want to fade a image and adjust the opacity in LibreOffice. So that I can write over it. I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Yes. There is a watermark option. But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: This might be helpful: LibreOffice has there own Q&A site: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/40435/how-do-i-put-a-watermark-in-the-background/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit a hidden feature in LibreOffice, it is not where you would expect it to be, but it is there:

1. Make sure the Picture Toolbox is enabled: select from the menu:

   View > Toolbars > Picture
2. (Probably at the bottom), the picture tools become visible. Edit the transparancy:

   [image]
3. Right click on the image, set "Wrap" to "In Background":

   [image]
4. Right click again on the image, set "Anchor" to "To Page":

   [image]
5. And you're done:

   [image]